# Как с помощью linq отсеять элементы в двух массивах?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть 2 строковых массива с большим количеством строк.

```
string[] words1;
string[] words2;
```

Если в этих двух массивах находится совпадение по заданному мной условию, нужно оба элемента добавить в разные листы/массивы. Примерный код:

```
            List<string> russian = new List<string>();
            sr = new StreamReader(@"russian.txt");//1 строка=1 слово русского языка
            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                russian.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }//примерно 1.5 миллиона строк
            int[] qw = { -1 };//индексы, которые надо игнорировать, сейчас не используется
            var a = russian.Where(q => q.Length == 8);//отсеиваем все слова с 8 буквами
            var b = a.Where(q => Check(q, qw));//отсеиваем слова с повторяющимися буквами
            var a1 = russian.Where(q => q.Length == 7);//отсеиваем все слова с 7 буквами
            var b1 = a1.Where(q => Check(q, qw));//отсеиваем слова с повторяющимися буквами
            string[] word1 = b.ToArray();//46к строк
            string[] word2 = b1.ToArray();//43к строк
            List<string> word11 = new List<string>();
            List<string> word22 = new List<string>();
            for(int i=0;i<word1.Length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1; j<word2.Length;j++)
                {
                    if(word1[i][0]==word2[j][0]&& word1[i][4] == word2[j][2] && word1[i][7] == word2[j][6])
                    {
                        if (!word11.Exists(q => q.Equals(word1[i])))
                            word11.Add(word1[i]);
                        if (!word22.Exists(q => q.Equals(word2[j])))
                            word22.Add(word2[j]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
                }
            }
```

```
        static bool Check(string str,int[] ind)//проверяет, имеет ли строка повторяющиеся символы, int[] ind - игнорируемые индексы
        {
            bool q=true;
            string a = "";
            int t=0;
            for(int i=0;i<str.Length;i++)
            {
                if (i != ind[t])
                    a += str[i];
                else
                {
                    i++;t++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j=i+1;j<a.Length;j++)
                {
                    if (a[i] == a[j])
                        q = false;
                }
            }
            return q;
        }
```

Но в лучшем случае он будет выполняться целые сутки.
Как с помощью linq выполнить этот же код?
UPD:
Вот пример попроще:

```
            string[] a1 = { "apple", "nilmar", "anpsa" };
            string[] a2 = { "ars", "aep", "fff", "arp" };
```

Нужно из массивов вытянуть те элементы, у которых первый и третий символы совпадают, т.е. в идеале должно быть два листа

```
            List<string> word1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> word2 = new List<string>();
```

Где в первом будут лежать "apple" и "anpsa", а во втором "aep" и "arp"

Comment: Есть ощущение, что для вашего примера linq только еще больше замедлит выполнение.

Comment: А Какого типа условие?

Comment: И можно пример ожилаемого результата, максимально валидный для вашей задачи

Comment: Здесь требуется не переход к linq, а уход от полного перебора элементов - он имеет сложность O(N^2), использовать не массивы, а хеш таблицы.

Comment: @AzizUmarov добавил пример

Comment: `b.ToArray()` так нельзя делать для больших данных. Покажите больше кода.

Comment: `с большим количеством строк` это сколько? Я 4 гиговый файл за 20 минут обрабатывал. Покажите ВЕСЬ код. `лучшем случае он будет выполняться целые сутки` сколько петабайт данных, говорите?

Comment: @aepot добавил весь код, по итогу получается 46к*43к итераций, счетчик i увеличивается на 1 примерно за 2 секунды, поэтому, по грубым подсчетам, у меня сутки получились

Comment: `Check(q, qw)` - нужен код этого метода

Comment: @aepot добавил код метода

Comment: Почему вы в массивы берете `b` и `b1` а не `a1` и `b1`? Ошибка?

Comment: @aepot так получилось, не ошибка. `b` и `b1` это пропарсенные масивы с 8-ю и с 7-ю буквами соответственно

Comment: Да, понял, запутался в именованиях ваших переменных. Старайтесь больше осмысленности давать в названиях переменных.

Comment: А вы готовы выложить куда-то данные и потом удалить? Или задача уже неактуальна? А то может обсудим [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--) [вопрос как данную задачу](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57512326#57512326) лучше решать - возможно пригодится в будущем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал немного оптимизировать

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] qw = Array.Empty<int>();

    List<string> words1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> words2 = new List<string>();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader("russian.txt"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string word = sr.ReadLine();
            if (word.Length == 8 && Check(word, qw))
                words1.Add(word);
            else if (word.Length == 7 && Check(word, qw))
                words2.Add(word);
        }
    }
    // для контроля уникальности используем специально оптимизированные для этого коллекции
    HashSet<string> result1 = new HashSet<string>();
    HashSet<string> result2 = new HashSet<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < words1.Count; i++)
    {
        string w1 = words1[i]; // кешируем ссылку на строку, чтобы не обращаться много раз через индекс
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words2.Count; j++)
        {
            string w2 = words2[j];
            if (w1[0] == w2[0] && w1[4] == w2[2] && w1[7] == w2[6])
            {                        
                result1.Add(w1);
                result2.Add(w2);
            }
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines("words1.txt", result1);
    File.WriteAllLines("words2.txt", result2);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

// индексы должны быть уникальны и отсортированы по возрастанию
// если нет индеков для исключения, массив индексов должен быть пустым
static bool Check(string str, int[] indexes) 
{
    string word = str.ToLower();
    if (indexes.Length == 0)
        return word.Distinct().Count() == word.Length;

    HashSet<char> distinct = new HashSet<char>();
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        while (Array.BinarySearch(indexes, i) >= 0)
            i++;
        if (i == word.Length)
            break;
        if (!distinct.Add(word[i++]))
            return false.
    }
    return true;
}
```

> Если у вас так быстро выполняется, не могли бы, пожалуйста, добавить третье слово из 6 букв с условием `w1[0] == w2[0] && w1[4] == w2[2] && w1[7] == w2[6]&& w3[1] == w2[1] && w3[3] == w1[3] && w3[4] == w2[2] && w3[4] == w1[4]` и скинуть результаты?

3 уровня вложенности - это очень долго, я бы сказал - кубическая сложность здесь будет выполняться вечность, но вот, я немного распараллелил код на уровне внешнего цикла, он кушает весь процессор полностью.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] qw = Array.Empty<int>();

    List<string> words1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> words2 = new List<string>();
    List<string> words3 = new List<string>();
    using (var sr1 = new StreamReader("russian.txt"))
    {
        while (!sr1.EndOfStream)
        {
            string word = sr1.ReadLine();
            if (word.Length == 8 && Check(word, qw))
                words1.Add(word);
            else if (word.Length == 7 && Check(word, qw))
                words2.Add(word);
            else if (word.Length == 6 && Check(word, qw))
                words3.Add(word);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", words1.Count, words2.Count, words3.Count));

    HashSet<string> result1 = new HashSet<string>();
    HashSet<string> result2 = new HashSet<string>();
    HashSet<string> result3 = new HashSet<string>();

    using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(Environment.ProcessorCount * 2);
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words1.Count; i++)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        Console.Write(i + " ");
        string w1 = words1[i];
        int ii = i;
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int j = ii + 1; j < words2.Count; j++)
            {
                string w2 = words2[j];
                for (int k = j + 1; k < words3.Count; k++)
                {
                    string w3 = words3[k];
                    if (w1[0] == w2[0] && w1[4] == w2[2] && w1[7] == w2[6] && w3[1] == w2[1] && w3[3] == w1[3] && w3[4] == w2[2] && w3[4] == w1[4])
                    {
                        lock (result1) result1.Add(w1);
                        lock (result2) result2.Add(w2);
                        lock (result3) result3.Add(w3);
                    }
                }
            }
            semaphore.Release();
        }));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result1.Count, result2.Count, result3.Count));

    File.WriteAllLines("words1.txt", result1);
    File.WriteAllLines("words2.txt", result2);
    File.WriteAllLines("words3.txt", result3);
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Добавил `Console.Write` во внешнем цикле, чтобы отслеживать позицию.

Comment: Если медленно, можно попробовать свести к одной вычитке файла вместо двух.

Comment: По скорости примерно так же, как и мой вариант, думаю, дело в моем процессоре. Но все равно спасибо

Comment: @OLIMP еще раз обновил код, немного перестарался в предыдущий раз

Comment: Чуть пошустрее, но все же не для моего процессора задача. Придется знакомых просить

Comment: @OLIMP со `StreamReader`? Здесь самое медленное - чтение файла. Процессор играет второстепенную роль.

Comment: Считывается то все шустренько, фор лупы все время забирают. 46к*43к, как-никак. Запустил программу на vps - раз в 5 быстрее работает, чем у меня

Comment: @OLIMP ну почти 1ккк итераций, конечно не быстро. Ну значит пока я сделал все что мог, дальше только распараллеливание, но без точных исходных данных и конкретного условия задачи это сделать невозможно. Да и кода получится раза в 3 больше.

Comment: В рамках текущего подхода можно попробовать задать capacity обоих хешсетов при инициализации - поможет избежать постоянного перерасчёта хеш-таблиц. Я бы сразу задал в половину от words.Count

Comment: Спросил автора, не готов ли он данные временно выложить куда-нибудь, любопытно стало как можно улучшить.

Comment: @AK в чате ответил

Comment: @AK `Я бы сразу задал в половину от words.Count` там если и будет прирост, то совсем незначительный, потому что по факту внутрь `if` с добавлением оно попадает кака я понял, не часто. Просто лярд проверок с выдергиванием 6 символов по индексу из 2 строк (6 лярдов обращений к индексаторам) - это тормоза. Возможно здесь `unsafe` прокатит, но я за грамотное распараллеливание как минимум по количеству ядер `Environment.ProcessorsCount`, хотя можно и то и другое сразу.

Comment: @OLIMP забрал ваши данные, нашел баг, например что `А` и `а` считаются разными буквами. Исправил метод `Check`. У меня код работает около 10 секунд.

Comment: @OLIMP попробуйте собрать еще релизный билд с оптимизацией кода, и запустить без отладчика. Оно точно быстрее отработает.

Comment: Если у вас так быстро выполняется, не могли бы, пожалуйста, добавить третье слово из 6 букв с условием `w1[0] == w2[0] && w1[4] == w2[2] && w1[7] == w2[6]&& w3[1] == w2[1] && w3[3] == w1[3] && w3[4] == w2[2] && w3[4] == w1[4]` и скинуть результаты?

Comment: @OLIMP не совсем понимаю, как огранизованы циклы должны быть для 3 списков. Покажите код в вопросе. Или дайте сюда в коммент ссылку на текст с кодом.

Comment: @aepot https://cumz.one/9pzedVN.cs как-то так

Comment: @OLIMP уберите `Console.WriteLine` из цикла, он вам всё и тормозит.

Comment: А ведь действительно, `Console.WriteLine` все и тормозил. Дико извиняюсь за вынос вашего мозга

Comment: @OLIMP в любом случае в 3 уровня вложенности выполняется очень долго. Я распараллелил код, он работает на всех ядрах процессора, но даже несмотря на то что я собрал релизную версию, все равно это долго. Чуть позже опубликую полную версию в ответе. Вот пока я пишу этот коммент оно обработало 1000 позиций из внешнего цикла.

Comment: @OLIMP добавил распараллеленый код. Не забудьте запускать на релизном билде.

Comment: @OLIMP нашел кртическую ошибку, пришлось прервать выполнение `result1.Add(w1); result2.Add(w2); result2.Add(w3);` в вашем коде было. `result2,result2`. Исправил код в ответе.

Comment: @AK попробовал `unsafe`, попробовал даже SSE2, пока самый быстрый вариант - тот что в ответе.

Comment: по поводу `Check` - 1) проще сделать hashSet из индексов, чем искать так `while (Array.BinarySearch(indexes, i) >= 0)` 2) можно функцию прервать если результат операции `distinct.Add(word[i++]);` будет false

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, верно. Но первая часть кода отрабатывает и так почти мгновенно. То есть там нет проблем с оптимизацией. `Check` частично поправил.